# What is the difference between 'char()' and 'char' in c++

Tags: c++

I stumbled across this while I was writing `boost::spirit::qi` rules. I write an incorrect rule declaration that I fixed by adding the brackets. It occurred to me that I do not know why this makes a difference.

What is the difference between `char` and `char()`?

Here is a minimal example that shows where this would be relevant.

Test `A` and `B` are equivalent. Test `C` compiles but fails the tests.
Test `D` is commented out and would not compile with the message: `C2440: 'static_cast' : cannot convert from 'skipper_type' to 'char'`. (With a slightly more complicated type the error would be `C2664`)

The test example is just to illustrate where the use of `char` vs `char()` makes a difference. My question is what the difference between the two is.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#define BOOST_TEST_MODULE Main
#include <boost/test/unit_test.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>

using std::string;
namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;
using Iterator = std::string::iterator;
using Skipper = qi::space_type;

Skipper skipper = qi::space;

void CHECK_ITERATOR(Iterator p, Iterator end)
{
    if (p != end)
    {
        BOOST_CHECK_MESSAGE(p == end, "Remaining: " << string(p, end));
    }
}

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(parse_char_type_B)
{
    qi::rule<Iterator, Skipper, char()> rule = qi::char_;

    char expected = 'B';
    char actual = 0;
    string toParse(&expected, (&expected) + 1);
    Iterator it = toParse.begin();
    BOOST_REQUIRE(qi::phrase_parse(it, toParse.end(), rule, skipper, actual));
    CHECK_ITERATOR(it, toParse.end());
    BOOST_CHECK_EQUAL(expected, actual);
}

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(parse_char_type_C)
{
    qi::rule<Iterator, Skipper, char> rule = qi::char_;

    char expected = 'C';
    char actual = 0;
    string toParse(&expected, (&expected) + 1);
    Iterator it = toParse.begin();
    BOOST_REQUIRE(qi::phrase_parse(it, toParse.end(), rule, skipper, actual));
    CHECK_ITERATOR(it, toParse.end());
    BOOST_CHECK_EQUAL(expected, actual);
}

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(parse_char_type_D)
{
    //qi::rule<Iterator, char, Skipper> rule = qi::char_;

    char expected = 'D';
    char actual = 0;
    string toParse(&expected, (&expected) + 1);
    Iterator it = toParse.begin();
    //BOOST_REQUIRE(qi::phrase_parse(it, toParse.end(), rule, skipper, actual));
    //CHECK_ITERATOR(it, toParse.end());
    //BOOST_CHECK_EQUAL(expected, actual);
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`char()` is a function type with no parameters, returning a `char`.

`char` is the default type for representing characters.

Of course, that's just in contexts where types are expected. Other contexts are different, e.g. `char a = char();` value-initializes `a`.